# hibernate is not locating hibernate.cfg.xml file

Tags: java, xml, scala, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate framework and I have the problem that it always looks for the hibernate.cfg.xml file inside test/resources/META-INF/ folder, in testing or when I run the app.

The configuration is this one:

```
object hibernateUtils{
  private val cfg = new Configuration
  cfg.configure("META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml")
  val sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory
}
```

Always looks for the test configuration, and I don't want to put an absolute path, I want it to look for the file inside the resource folder.

The configuration object is under main/scala/utils/. I'm using hava and scala in the app.

Does anyone know how can I solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with

```
cfg.configure("classpath:utils/META-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml")
```

If it doesn't work, just check where the classpath is pointing to and use relative path from there.

Comment: It says that it coudn't find it. I want it to point to the reource folder, not to the src. I don't know why it look for it in test instead of main, I think it has to be the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Why putting hibernate cfg in META-INF and not in src ?

Comment: Because I want to have it inside the resources folder inside main, because I have another configuration in test/resources, which it loads running the app and it don't have to be like that.